# Python GDAL: Count the number of pixels of the raster image using a range of pixel values

Tags: python, count, range, pixel, gdal

I have some raster files and I want to count the number of pixels in each file with pixel values falling in between some specific range. I tried the following code, though it runs but produces wrong number of pixels.

Code:

```
import os, sys
import numpy as np
import gdalnumeric
path = ('dir')
os.chdir(path)
for rasters in os.listdir(path):
    raster_file = gdalnumeric.LoadFile(rasters)
    pixel_count = (raster_file =>0 & <= 25).sum()
    print(pixel_count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a little bit off - I don't think it compiles, but with

```py
((raster_file >= 0) & (raster_file <= 25)).sum()
```

you should get a correct result

Comment: No, it is does run but gives the wrong output. Pertinently to mention here is that the code gives the right results when I use the equals e.g., `  (raster_file == 25) `, but when I use a range it provides the wrong result.

Comment: what is the data type? if your code does run, you did not copy it properly, this function has a syntax error

Comment: It is a raster file and in tiff format. And I was able to figure out the problem. I changed the `no-data` value of the file which was unfortunately set to `0`. Now the results are perfect. Thanks for your response @ mmomtchev